# Will the save file for the retail version of Persona 4 Arena work with the digital version?

Tags: psn, persona-4-arena

I’m planning to get the “Ultimate Edition” from PSN that includes all the DLC. However, will the save file for my retail copy work on this version?

Comment: @Nolonar - It's a PS3 game, it's a disc! :P  In regards to the question, my impression is that 99% of titles don't care how they're running and will share save data, but I'm not absolutely certain of that so I'll just leave it with this comment.

Comment: @Shinrai Oops... I saw Persona 4, so I was thinking about the Vita; sorry about the confusion. If it's the PS3 then yes, it doesn't matter if the game is from the disc or PSN; saves and DLCs will work for both versions.

Comment: I went ahead, bought it and the save file didn't work. See my response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead, bought the game, and sadly the save files aren't compatible. The save file of the retail version is named:

```
Persona 4 ARENA
```

While the PSN version is called

```
Persona 4 ARENA [DL]
```

Why this is the case is beyond me. The fact that I won't be able to use my old save file is very depressing.

Comment: Sorry about hearing this :( At least the DLC will work for both versions, since there aren't any separate versions on the PSN (though there's still the possibility of encountering different language/region versions of the same DLC)