# Persona 4 Arena to Ultimax save games

Tags: persona-4-arena, persona-4-arena-ultimax

Is there any carry-over of save games between the original Persona 4 Arena and Person 4 Arena Ultimax?

Asking because I have the original on 360 and have ordered Ultimax on PS3 and I'm wondering if I should get the PS3 version of the original to go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. They are different games, and have no save game carryover.

On a side note, [the save files for the digital version and physical copy of P4A aren't compatible either](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/118793/38606).